# Getting 'numpy.int64' object is not callable and "Size mismatch between tensors" errors in PyTorch while building an MLP

Tags: pandas, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, multi-layer

I have 4 text files,one of which includes `x1`,`x2`,`x3` as training features and the other one is y for labels and the same applies to testing.
I have to construct a Multi Layer Perceptron (MLP) model in Pytorch
and what I did was to load these text files to PyTorch under the names of `x_train`,`y_train`,`x_test` and `y_test`.
However when I run the code below:

```py
dataset_train = data.TensorDataset(x_train,y_train)
dataloader_train =data.DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True,num_workers=0)
```

I get this error :

```
'numpy.int64' object is not callable
```

I also see this : `Size mismatch between tensors`.
please help me with this error,what does it mean and what I have to change ?

Comment: so I tried to convert them to tensors but nothing changed using these codes :       '''tensor_ = torch.from_numpy(x_train.to_numpy().astype(np.int64))'''

Comment: Have you checked the size of all tensors? They should be same.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example so we can help you better. Also currently this is too vague you need to add more details as well otherwise you might get down-voted and get your question closed